# Grails: plugin injecting service into src groovy within a plugin

Tags: grails

Apologies, since there are lots of links out there and I have tried a few examples including stuff that already works within my project(s) that are non plugin:

What I have tried:

Within my Plugin descriptor:

```
def doWithSpring = {
        someService(SomeService)
    }
```

Then within my end src/groovy

```
//def someService = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean 'someService'
def someService
```

None of above works...

If I instantiate the service everything appears to work fine, I would prefer to inject it and its just taking a lot of time doing something rather basic :(

SomeService someService=new SomeService()

Any help would be appreciated

Not that I have ever seen it before (within a plugin) should I include conf/spring/resources.groovy and initialise bean in there ?

Comment: How is your src/groovy class invoked - from a controller? Service?

Comment: Hi Burt. Its an endpoint for websockets hence invoked directly from a gsp. https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-jenkins-plugin/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/jenkins/JenkinsEndPoint.groovy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, like most cases, there's a way to access what you want without using holders. The Groovy class implements `ServletContextListener`, so there's a `contextInitialized` method with a `ServletContextEvent` event containing the `ServletContext`. So it wasn't necessary to use the `ServletContextHolder` to get the `ServletContext` - it was right there. You can see from the [FAQ](https://grails.org/FAQ) that the Spring `ApplicationContext` is stored in the `ServletContext` as an attribute. Once you have that, you can access whatever Spring beans you want; in this case the `jenkinsService` and the `grailsApplication` beans (you can get the config directly from the `grailsApplication` without using `Holders` for that.

I made these changes and did a bunch of cleanup, and sent a pull request.

Comment: Thanks Burt. You are my hero :)

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your service in a `src/groovy` class like so:

```
import com.example.SomeService
import grails.util.Holders

class SrcGroovy {

    SomeService someService = Holders.applicationContext.getBean("someService")

    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks Ken, will try this it looks a little different to my version above

Comment: this is causing some strange issues - the src/groovy file is an endpoint and it returns :  a 404 and The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. ...

Comment: That's not injecting, it's pulling in an external resource. Rod and the Spring team spent all that time developing a great framework using dependency injection and inversion of control, and now we're going back to the old way. Nope, not me :)

Comment: @Burt, learning to be a better Grails developer would be tough without you. When I read @vahid’s question, I thought of a case where I implement ```HttpSessionListener```, and as you pointed out, I don’t need the ```Holders``` class because I have access to ```HttpSessionEvent```. If you had a class with several different methods, each with access to ```ServletContext```, would you pull in the external resource once using ```Holders```, or would you use ```servletContext.getAttribute(GA.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)``` in each method? Is it a case of  using toMAYtoes or toMAtoes?

Comment: @BurtBeckwith. I've been doing some refactoring. Is this post (http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=993) still the preferred technique for getting ```grailsApplication``` in a domain class?